# Ошибка при сборке docker container

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

Я пытаюсь собрать докер контейнер из моего образа. При запуске этой команды `docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml up --build` выходит такая ошибка: `failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to solve with frontend gateway.v0: invalid reference format`
Это довольно таки странно потому что я следовал официальной документации [docker](https://docs.docker.com/language/python/develop/).

Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:

FROM python:3.9.7

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

docker-compose.dev.yml:

```yaml
version: '3.9.7'

services:
 web:
  build:
   context: .
  ports:
  - 8000:5000
  volumes:
  - ./:/app
```

Comment: Проверьте, что ваш файл называется `Dockerfile`

Comment: Проверил. Файл называется как `Dockerfile`

Comment: просто чтобы исключить многое, запустите `docker build -t tem_image -f <path to your dockerfile> . `.  в вашем конкретном случае это будет `docker build -t tem_image -f Dockerfile .` и не забудьте точку в конце. покажите результат. собирается?

Comment: благодарю ! ваш комментарий мне помог ! Если вам не сложно, не могли бы вы оформить ваш комментарий как ответ ?